# inserting data through HABTM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a HABTM association between Users and Workspaces, which also has groups. The problem is I can't insert data intro groups from users.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :workspaces #,  dependent: :destroy
 has_many :groups,                       through: :workspaces 
end 

class Workspace < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many   :users,            dependent: :destroy 
  has_many                  :groups,           dependent: :destroy 
end
```

This is the join table migration:

```
class CreateUsersAndWorkspaces < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users_workspaces, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true
      t.belongs_to :workspace, index: true
    end
  end
end
```

In rails console, when I try to create new group:

```
 u.groups.create!(name: "txt", workspace_id: 1 )                                                                                      
 (0.1ms)  begin transaction
 (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
  ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughNestedAssociationsAreReadonly: 
  Cannot modify  association 'User#groups' because it goes 
  through more than one other association.
```

Is there a way to create groups from the user?

EDIT:
With help from @evedovelli I could make it work. but since user.workspace was a ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy, it was not a workspace class, but a collection. appending 'first', solved the problem, so the final code is:

```
u.workspaces(id: 1).first.groups.create!(name: "txt")
```

Now suppose I have more associations:

```
u.workspaces(id: 1).first.groups(id: 2).first.modelN(id:3).first.modelNplus1.create!(name: "txt")
```

my final question is, is this the correct way?

Comment: The problem is that Rails cannot find out to what workspace the group from user should be added to (even if you to specify the worspace_id on creation as you did).

Since you known the workspace id when creating the group, can't you simply create with `u.workspaces(id: 1).groups.create!(name: "txt")`?

This way it may create the group for the right user's workspace. (I'll will enter this as an answer)

Comment: Just updated the answer. Use `find_by_id` to search by the correct id in the model. `first` will always returns the first item from the list, and that's not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Rails cannot find out to what **user**'s **workspace** the **group** should be added to (even if you to specify the worspace_id on creation as you did).

As mentioned in the error message, the nested associations for `HasManyThrough` are read only. So you can read **groups** directly from an **user**, but you can't create them.

Since you known the `workspace_id` when creating the group, you can simply create the group with:

```
u.workspaces.find_by_id(1).groups.create!(name: "txt")
```

This way it will create the **group** for the right **user**'s **workspace**.

And you should be able to keep going with that through other associations like this:

```
u.workspaces.find_by_id(1).groups.find_by_id(2).modelN.find_by_id(3).modelNplus1.create!(name: "txt")
```

Comment: I am able to 
     worksp.groups.create!(name: "txt")
but not 
    u.workspaces(id: 1).groups.create!(name: "txt")

    NoMethodError: undefined method `groups' for #
    <Workspace::ActiveRecord_Associations_
    CollectionProxy:0x00000005bcefd0>